# How to claim unclaimed memory for Intel Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM?

Tags: linux, driver, intel, ram, s

I have recently come across a hardware component on my computer system called "Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM" from Intel Corporation. Upon checking the system information, I found the following details about the SRAM module:

```
memory UNCLAIMED
description: RAM memory
product: Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:a55a0000-a55a1fff memory:a55a6000-a55a6fff
```

This looks like a driver issue to me, but I couldn't find any "Nobara Linux" driver site to update the driver.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have any connection to programming, so you should ask it at https://superuser.com instead.  When you do, you should explain what tool produced the output you quote, how you ran it, what command line arguments, etc.

Comment: "Unclaimed" might just mean that you don't have a driver for this device.  If it's not something whose functionality you care about, then that's fine and you can just ignore it.  The "memory" listed may not be actual memory, just an indication of the address where the I/O is mapped, and there's only 192K of it anyway so not worth taking any trouble over.

Comment: So when you repost, you should also explain if there is some particular feature you're trying to make use of, or if you have observed your system misbehaving in some way that you think is related, or if it's just that you think the "unclaimed" message looks concerning.